# Javafx by kotlin went wrong when I export it to runnable jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, jar, kotlin

I try to write javafx application using kotlin. After I export it to runnable jar,I double click jar file but it doesn't work. But everything ok if I use Java.

For example: Create a new javafx project by IDEA 2017.2.5.Select File-Project Structure,then click JavaFX tab,Native bundle choose all.Then apply setting.
[image]

Then choose Build-Build Artifact-Build.
[image]

I can run it.Everything OK.
[image]

But when I use kotlin and do same thing as java.
Everything ok when I run it in IDEA.

code:

```
package sample

import javafx.application.Application
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader
import javafx.scene.Parent
import javafx.scene.Scene
import javafx.stage.Stage

class Main : Application() {

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun start(primaryStage: Stage) {
        val root = FXMLLoader.load<Parent>(javaClass.getResource("sample.fxml"))
        primaryStage.title = "Hello World"
        primaryStage.scene = Scene(root, 300.0, 275.0)
        primaryStage.show()
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            Application.launch(Main::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
I double click it but nothing happend.What's wrong???

Comment: class loader behaves different when you run as jar. (directory level) instead of using FXMLLoader. Try loading from path instead.... javaClass.getResource("/").toURI().resolve("sample.fxml").getPath(); <-- load this path

Comment: Please don't repost your question. Delete or edit your previous one.